# Rate at zero idiomatic

Tags: idiomatic-language

When saying that I am bad at something can I use "I rate myself at zero"? Does this sound idiomatic? For example, I can't dance. I rate myself at zero. I mean on scale of 1 to 10.

Comment: You can't rate at zero on a scale of one to ten... the lowest rating on that scale is one.

Comment: @JamesK On a pedantic scale of 1 to 10, that's an 11. ;)

Answer (score 2):

"Rate myself **a** zero" is a [more common and idiomatic phrasing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rate+myself+a%2Crate+myself+at&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), at least in US English.  It's like you are assigning yourself a score, which is *a zero*.

Comment: That would be true in any English. I just don't get why people say BrE and AmE when it is not relevant.

Comment: True, but is it idiomatic or even correct to say "*...**at** zero*"?

Comment: @Lambie I'm just saying that I'm not sure if it would be considered idiomatic in other dialects, since I don't know them all.  On ELL I've discovered a number of surprising differences between BrE and AmE that I would not have even thought of.

Comment: @gotube I haven't found very many examples of "rate myself *at*" - maybe one or two, like https://books.google.com/books?id=aaLJCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT250&dq=%22rate+myself+at%22+%22out+of+ten%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwian7KDw9j7AhW1rHIEHZp-DAcQ6AF6BAgIEAI

Comment: If one had a scale of 1 to 20, say, one could conceivably say "at some number", of course. But with zero, I would say rate myself a zero, not at. //stangdon, I don't consider that what is basically standard English to have *dialectal* differences.